# Name for a Chainable ForEach

Tags: c#, naming, linq

Linq has a method `Select`, which takes a `Func<TIn, TOut>` and maps it over an iterable.

I'm trying to come up with a good name for a method that takes an `Action <TIn>`, transforms it to return its argument, and maps *that* over an iterable.

The method is

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMap<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    return source.Select(i => {action(i); return i;});
}
```

The initial use for this would be binding events on objects:

```
Controls.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n => new Button(){Text = n.ToString()}).MyMap(b => b.Click += NumberButton_Click).ToArray());
```

In C#6, this is redundant as object initializers can bind events, but I'm stuck in 5 (where it's invalid to do so) for the forseeable future for corporate reasons.

I'm aware of `List.ForEach`, but that's a `void` method, I want something I can chain, as seen above.

Edit: `Button` example was just an example of how I would use it.

The code it would be used in is closer to

```
private void DoStuff(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    var fooList = foos.ToList();
    foreach (var foo in fooList)
    {
        Foo localFoo = foo;
        localFoo.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var newArgs = new FooBarEventArgs(localFoo.Bar, e.Baz);
                this.OnFooBar(newArgs)
            };
    }

    _wrappedClass.DoStuff(fooList);
}
```

So I don't have control over creation of the `IEnumerable`, and there isn't a single element equivalent to `DoStuff`.  However, with `MyMap`, it becomes (IMHO) cleaner:

```
private void DoStuff(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    _wrappedClass.DoStuff(foos.MyMap(f => f.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => this.OnFooBar(new FooBarEventArgs(f.Bar, e.Baz)));
}
```

Comment: How about Do(), Each() or Exec()? Since this is only going to be in your specific domain, you should choose whatever reads best for your audience == your current+future developers

Comment: How about "SmellyTransform" 8-O? Honestly, when you start using Linq with side effects, this quickly becomes a code smell. Linq functions with modifying effects will at least violate the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: ChainableForEach

Answer (score 11):

Linq functions with modifying effects will at least violate the principle of least astonishment, so what you have in mind is a code smell, to my understanding.

For your use case, I think it is **much** more readable when you do not try to push as many command into one line as you can. Why not write a function like

```
IEnumerable<Button> CreateButtons()
{
     for(int n=0;i<10;++n)
     {
         var b = new Button();
         b.Text=n.ToString();
         b.Click += NumberButton_Click;
         yield return b;
     }
 }
```

However, if you still want to achieve this with one Linq expression, try

```
        Controls.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(
            n => {
                var b = new Button();
                b.Text = n.ToString();
                b.Click += NumberButton_Click;
                return b;
            }));
```

I would even consider to put the button creation into a named function like `CreateButton(int n)`, this leaves you with

```
Controls.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select( n => CreateButton(n)));
```

This way, you do not need to invent a smelly `MyMap` function.

To your 2nd example: IMHO the first variant without `MyMap` can be made more comprehensive by leaving out the unnecessary local variables. However, putting the event handler stuff into a `Select` expression works similar:

```
wrappedClass.DoStuff(foos.Select(f => 
   { 
       f.ValueChanged += 
             (sender, e) => this.OnFooBar(new FooBarEventArgs(f.Bar, e.Baz));
       return f;
   }));
```

Nevertheless this is a solution with side effects. For increased readability, why not give the operation which adds the handlers a name?

```
IEnumerable<Foo> AddHandlers( IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
     foreach (f in foos)
     {
        f.ValueChanged += 
             (sender, e) => this.OnFooBar(new FooBarEventArgs(f.Bar, e.Baz));
        yield return f;
     }
 }
```

Comment: See edit for better example of the context I'll be using it in.

Comment: The last code example could just use the method group.

Comment: @RoadieRich: as a side note, I recommend Eric Lippert's blog entry about ForEach and side effects: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/ So do yourself a favor and avoid creating Linq queries with side effects, your program's quality will benefit from this.

Answer (score 3):

The [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library has this method and calls it `Pipe`, which I find very appropriate.

> **Pipe**   |   Executes the given action on each element in the source sequence and yields it

If you're interested - you can see it's source code [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Pipe.cs).